# Azure yaml pipeline : get deploy SQL script from task SqlAzureDacpacDeployment

Tags: azure-pipelines-yaml, dacpac, cicd

We use SqlAzureDacpacDeployment task to deploy changes to database. But our DBAs want to approve deployment script before deploy will be executed itself.

SqlAzureDacpacDeployment task obviously can generate a script

```
- task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
  displayName: Task "Generate SQL Script"
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ******
    AuthenticationType: servicePrincipal
    ServerName: ******
    DatabaseName: ******
    DeploymentAction: Script
    DacpacFile:  '****.dacpac'
    AdditionalArguments: '/p:ExcludeObjectTypes=Users;Logins;RoleMembership;Permissions /p:ScriptDatabaseOptions=false'
```

But the script is available only after pipeline is finished and only in logs

[image]

Is it possible to get a script after the SqlAzureDacpacDeployment task is completed. For example save it to artifacts?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this, but I would try adding an output path to AdditionalArguments and then publishing that artifact.

```
- task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
  displayName: Task "Generate SQL Script"
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ******
    AuthenticationType: servicePrincipal
    ServerName: ******
    DatabaseName: ******
    DeploymentAction: Script
    DacpacFile:  '****.dacpac'
    AdditionalArguments: '/p:ExcludeObjectTypes=Users;Logins;RoleMembership;Permissions /p:ScriptDatabaseOptions=false /OutputPath:"$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)"'
```